# Composer: Specify a version for the requiring package?

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, version

If I create a composer package (module/extension/add-on/plug-in) for an application or a framework, is it possible to specify the version of the that 'parent'?

Example: A Magento extension that should be requireable by Magento 2, but not by Magento 1.

That would be some kind of a reversed version dependency.

Comment: Why not add parent to `require` section in `composer.json` of plugin?

Comment: You could also use either the [`conflict`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#conflict) or the [`suggest`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#suggest) fields I guess.